# How to do a mongo join query on optional fields

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Mongod 5.07 on Windows.  I would like to perform a join between two collections where I specify a match/where clause on an optional field in the joined table.  I have the following collections (for demonstration purposes only),

`sessions` collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6471024b01a1111088835c33"), "chat_id" : "4" }
```

and an item in the `events` collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6471024b01a1111088835c34"), "chat_id" : "3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6471024b01a1111088835c36"), "chat_id" : "4", "transcript": ["t2"] }
```

My aggregate statement uses the following:

```
query = [
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"events",
         "localField":"chat_id",
         "foreignField":"chat_id",
         "let":{
            "transcript":"$transcript"
         },
         "pipeline":[
            {
               "$match":{
                  "$expr":{
                     "$in":[
                        "t2",
                        "$$transcript"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "as":"events"
      }
   }
]
db.sessions.aggregate(query).forEach(printjson)
```

but I end up getting an error for what appears to be the missing `transcript` field

```
"PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing"
```

I am hoping to get a solution that is independent of the field type (i.e. not array specific, perhaps using $exists).  Any thoughts?

Comment: `"transcript":{"$ifNull":["$transcript", []]}`  and in pipeline `$$transcript` ? https://mongoplayground.net/p/LPfhKcEiq8z

Comment: Thanks, but your example has the transcript fields on the session objects and I need them on the events objects - I've clarified the question above.  I've tried with the fields moved, but then it fails to identify chat_id=4, https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ce7Ofn-1OQG.  Note that in the real use case I have conditions on both objects, so can't just reverse the join.

Comment: just a nomal lookup? https://mongoplayground.net/p/wI8WcQdsktS i dont know how the format should be and if there cn be multiple events for a session chat id